# Hardhat local transactions don't process

Tags: ether, ethers.js, ethereumjs, hardhat, blocks

I'm new to hardhat. I am playing around with the local hardhat accounts, which are all funded for 10k ETH. All I want to do is send some ETH from 1 account to another, and check the second account's balance and confirm that they did receive the transaction. Sounds simple enough, but I am having a hard time with it.

Here's my code:

```
const provider = new ethers.providers.JsonRpcProvider('http://127.0.0.1:8545')
const signer = provider.getSigner()

async function main() {
    // set up accounts
    const signers = await ethers.getSigners();
    acc1 = signers[0]
    acc2 = signers[1]

    // check balance before tx
    console.log('balance of account 2: ',await provider.getBalance(acc2.getAddress()))

    // sendtx of 500 ether from acc 1 to acc 2
    const tx = await acc1.sendTransaction({
    to: acc2.address,
    value: ethers.utils.parseEther("500"),
    });
    const receipt = await tx.wait()

    // check balance now
    console.log('balance of account 2: ',await provider.getBalance(acc2.getAddress()))
}
main()
```

Unfortunately, both `console.log` calls return `BigNumber { value: "10000000000000000000000" }` only, regardless of the transaction I am attempting to process. I have checked that the signers and provider are on the same network/chainId (they are, 31337). I checked block 0, and there are no transactions processed in block 0, but in block 1, the parentHash is the same as the blockHash from `receipt`, making me think my transaction is not being processed for whatever reason. I have tried using hardhat_mine to move the blocks through, but it is not working either. Can someone please provide me with the code that will allow me to see my simple transaction go through. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

To run scripts using hardhat, you need to run `npx hardhat run scripts/myscript.js` and **not** run it directly using node.

This will allow you to use hardhat's `ethers`, that is connected to the correct network. No need to define your own `ethers` and connect to an RPC.

Once you use hardhat network, it'll work properly -

```js
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

async function main() {
    // set up accounts
    const [acc1, acc2] = await ethers.getSigners();

    // check balance before tx
    console.log('balance of account 2: ', await ethers.provider.getBalance(acc2.getAddress()))

    // sendtx of 500 ether from acc 1 to acc 2
    const tx = await acc1.sendTransaction({
    to: acc2.address,
    value: ethers.utils.parseEther("500"),
    });
    const receipt = await tx.wait()

    // check balance now
    console.log('balance of account 2: ',await ethers.provider.getBalance(acc2.getAddress()))
}
main()
```

Now run this using `npx hardhat run scripts/.....js` (place your script name)

---

As a side note, to test stuff you better use hardhat's testing infrastructure.

For instance, create a file `test/basic.js` -

```js
const { expect } = require("chai");
const { ethers } = require("hardhat");

describe("Test", async () => {

    it("sends ether", async function () {
        const [first, second] = await ethers.getSigners();;

        expect(await ethers.provider.getBalance(second.address)).to.equal("10000000000000000000000");

        await first.sendTransaction({
            to: second.address,
            value: ethers.utils.parseEther("5"),
        });

        expect(await ethers.provider.getBalance(second.address)).to.equal("10005000000000000000000");
    });
});
```

Now run this test -

```
npx hardhat test
```